# docker and nginx: How to reverse proxy multiple postgresql databases

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx

I am having a docker container with multiple postgresql databases:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 8028:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/localhost/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    networks:
      - postgresql_network

  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../DO_NOT_DELETE_POSTGRESQL_DATA
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db1
      POSTGRES_USER: simha
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: krishna
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    networks:
      - postgresql_network

  postgresql2:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../DO_NOT_DELETE_POSTGRESQL_DATA2
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db2
      POSTGRES_USER: simha
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: krishna
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    networks:
      - postgresql_network

networks:
  postgresql_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now I can expose two different ports for each of the postgresq instance and access them differently from host (like localhost 5432 and localhost 5445)

But instead of that i want to handle them using different domain names.

like `pg1.docker.db`, port `8028` (nginx port) and `pg.docker.db`, port `8028` (nginx port) and using nginx reverse proxy them internally to different docker containers using `postgresql` and `postgresql2`

and in the host `/etc/hosts` I will have

```
127.0.0.1 pg1.docker.db
127.0.0.1 pg2.docker.db
```

I am not sure, but something similar. Can someone say I am doing right

```
## WEBSERVER

upstream webapp {
    server webapp:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


## POSTGRESQL DBS

upstream postgres {
    server postgresql:5432;
}

upstream postgres2 {
    server postgresql2:5432;
}

server {
    listen 80 so_keepalive=on;
    server_name db1.domain.my;
    proxy_pass postgres;
}

server {
    listen 80 so_keepalive=on;
    server_name db2.domain.my;
    proxy_pass postgres2;
}
```

I find people using `stream` and `http`. Will the above also work. Or should I do something

Comment: You’d have to make up your own protocol and create a switcher process for that. PostgreSQL protocol has no concept for this and Nginx is just a TCP proxy here, I assume

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting http requests based on domain name is pretty easy.
You can use something like this:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name pg1.docker.db
        location / {
            ...
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name pg2.docker.db;
        location / {
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

But the problem here is that nginx forward only http request to servers, so unless you have a web-base interface behind your containers, it's not going to work properly.